# Use FormData in an HTTP Response in Deno/Oak

Tags: response, multipart, form-data, deno, oak

I know that I can create a FormData in the client and send it to the server (in this case I'm using Deno/Oak), and read it from there.

But is this possible vice versa?

If I have a route in Oak, and I want it to send a multipart response (with one or more blobs, and with one or more strings), how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oak's [automatic response body handling](https://github.com/oakserver/oak#automatic-response-body-handling) supports [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) so you can set [`context.response.body`](https://github.com/oakserver/oak#response) to an instance of `FormData` and Oak will take care of the rest. e.g.:

```ts
import { Application } from "https://deno.land/x/oak@v9.0.0/mod.ts";

const app = new Application();

app.use((ctx) => {
  const data = new FormData();
  data.append("string1", "Hi");
  data.append("string2", "Bye");
  data.append("blob1", new Blob(['<a id="a">Hi</a>'], { type: "text/xml" }));
  data.append("blob2", new Blob(['<b id="b">Bye</b>'], { type: "text/xml" }));
  ctx.response.body = data;
});

await app.listen({ port: 8000 });
```

```console
% curl localhost:8000
------7115155097707325061106360125
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="string1"

Hi
------7115155097707325061106360125
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="string2"

Bye
------7115155097707325061106360125
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="blob1"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: text/xml

<a id="a">Hi</a>
------7115155097707325061106360125
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="blob2"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: text/xml

<b id="b">Bye</b>
------7115155097707325061106360125--
```

---

The same can be done directly in Deno without any additional framework:

```ts
const server = Deno.listen({ port: 8000 });

for await (const conn of server) serveHttp(conn);

async function serveHttp(conn: Deno.Conn) {
  const httpConn = Deno.serveHttp(conn);
  for await (const requestEvent of httpConn) {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("string1", "Hi");
    data.append("string2", "Bye");
    data.append("blob1", new Blob(['<a id="a">Hi</a>'], { type: "text/xml" }));
    data.append("blob2", new Blob(['<b id="b">Bye</b>'], { type: "text/xml" }));
    requestEvent.respondWith(new Response(data));
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help, mfulton26. It worked with curl, even with blobs from videos.Unfortunately, it isn't working on browser clients. Using Insomnia, it returns "Failed to parse multipart response: content-type missing boundary". I have tried with GET/POST, setting `context.response.headers.set("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")` previous to the Oak response of the body, and also adding/removing the `headers: {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}` in the client fetch, but with no luck.

Comment: Interesting, it works fine for me via `curl` and Chromium browsers but not in Insomnia… interestingly enough the native Deno solution I added previously to my answer here does work in Insomnia. The response headers are different too; `Deno.requestEvent`'` `resondWith` causes `Content-Type` to include a "boundary" in it (e.g. `multipart/form-data; boundary=----7830127428108890346214010889`) while the Oak solution does not. This might be a bug in Oak. I'm not sure yet. I haven't use Oak myself much. It only sends ` multipart/form-data`…

Comment: Okay, after a little more investigation it looks like Insomnia is actually receiving the response just fine. Its "Visual Preview", however, fails to parse the response. If you switch to view the response "Source Code" or "Raw Data" you'll see all the data as expected.

I've created 2 GitHub issues. If either gets fixed or provides some workaround, etc. then the "Visual Preview" should work for you too:

1. https://github.com/oakserver/oak/issues/400
2. https://github.com/Kong/insomnia/issues/4021

I suggest subscribing to those issues for updates.

Comment: Many many thanks again, @mfulton26. I have tried with Insomnia as you said and yes, it was working. In the client, using the fetch api, I receive the response like this: `.then(response => response.formData())`, but it says: "Could not parse content as FormData.", probably because of the missing boundary. Anyway, I have suscribe to the issue in Oak and I will stick to it.

Comment: FYI: A fix for https://github.com/oakserver/oak/issues/400 has been merged.

Answer (score 0):

To send many *blobs* in one HTTP response, I am using a solution based on Base64 string. It is inefficient (as base64 encoding increments +33% the size of the file encoded), but it works.

In the server:

```js
let URI_File = `/my/uri/file.mp4`;
const file = await Deno.open(URI_File);
const base64String = this.Lab.Library.base64Encode(await Deno.readAll(file));

const myObjectWithBlobs = {
myString: "hello",
myBlob: base64String
}

context.response.body = myObjectWithBlobs;
```

In the client, decoding the base64 string:

```js
await fetch(`https://example.com`, { method: 'POST' })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {

      const decodedBase64 = atob(data.myBlob);
      const arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(decodedBase64.length);
      const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);  
      for (let i = 0; i < decodedBase64.length; i++) {
        uint8Array[i] = decodedBase64.charCodeAt(i); 
      }
  
      // We get the blob (but many blobs could be send in the same response), so we could iterate them with .map()
      const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
    
  });
```

Hope that better solutions come in the future. If I encounter a better solution to this issue I will post it.